# Shadow Effect On Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, shadows, blending, bitmap

I'm working on press project that needs to trace almost exact with the picture attached and will save it as Bitmap later.

From what I know, there are 3 layers: gradient background, metal texture, and curve. I have a question for the curve; after I make the curve shape on AI, transfer it to PS, how can I make the same shadow effect in Photoshop and can blend onto background texture?

Thank you! :]

[image: how to make same curve effect]

Answer (score 5):

That's not a shadow effect as such. It's a **Motion Blur**.

```
Filter > Blur > Motion Blur...
```

Motion blur applies a blur effect to an object in a specified direction. In this case that direction is horizontal (0º). The screenshot below shows some settings that produce a result that is pretty close to what you are trying to achieve:

[image]